# how to connect server local domain from other workstation

Tags: networking, network-shares, webserver, windows-server-2012

I would like to type company.local as local domain instead of type in IP address to connect ti web host in IIS.

But i cannot connect company.local from other workstation unless i enter

127.0.0.1   localhost
server ip    company.local

at my workstation host file. this is very time consuming if my company have 1000 workstation, and it the local domain change i need change all work station.

anyone got idea to solve this issue?

It work on server side if i type company.local, the iis default page will prompt.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Does your company use a domain? You should just be able to use FQDN in the address bar or no domain at all.

```
http://company
```

or

```
http://company.mycompany.com
```

If that doesn't work you'll need to verify that your corporate DNS has all in-use suffixes registered so you inherit them from DNS when you get your DHCP IP address. If you use static addresses you have to manually add search domains.

NIC Properties > IPv4 > Properties > Advanced > DNS > "Append these DNS suffixes"